# openvpn TLS handshake error in centos7

Tags: vpn, openvpn, tls

I want to use openvpn from centos7, but been facing problems of TLS handshaking error (and WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.)

code of client.ovpn file

```
client
dev tap
proto udp
remote 202.79.XX.XXX 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
mute-replay-warnings
#ca wlink-ca.pem
ca ca.crt
comp-lzo
verb 3
auth-user-pass
route-method exe
route-delay 2
```

I have 4 files in /etc/openvpn

1. ca.crt
2. client.ovpn
3. easy-rsa
4. README.txt

Output:

```
sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn 
Wed Mar 15 11:22:31 2017 OpenVPN 2.3.14 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Dec  7 2016
Wed Mar 15 11:22:31 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013, LZO 2.06
Enter Auth Username: ***************
Enter Auth Password: *****
Wed Mar 15 11:22:45 2017 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Wed Mar 15 11:22:45 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Wed Mar 15 11:22:45 2017 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Wed Mar 15 11:22:45 2017 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]202.79.XX.XXX:1194
Wed Mar 15 11:22:45 2017 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]202.79.32.115:1194, sid=9b186f7d ff710a3f
Wed Mar 15 11:22:45 2017 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Wed Mar 15 11:22:46 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=NP, ST=Bagmati, L=Kathmandu, O=Worldlink, OU=System, CN=something, emailAddress=something@something.com.np
Wed Mar 15 11:22:46 2017 VERIFY ERROR: depth=0, error=certificate signature failure: C=NP, ST=Bagmati, O=Worldlink, OU=System, CN=something, emailAddress=something@something.com.np
Wed Mar 15 11:22:46 2017 OpenSSL: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Wed Mar 15 11:22:46 2017 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error
Wed Mar 15 11:22:46 2017 TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
Wed Mar 15 11:22:46 2017 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Wed Mar 15 11:22:46 2017 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Wed Mar 15 11:22:46 2017 Restart pause, 2 second(s)
^CWed Mar 15 11:22:47 2017 SIGINT[hard,init_instance] received, process exiting
e here
```

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Does the ovpn file have the public & private key made by easy-rsa embedded in it?

Comment: 01.pem  ca.key      client.csr  dh2048.pem  index.txt.attr  serial
ca.crt  client.crt  client.key  index.txt   index.txt.old   serial.old

These are the files in  /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/

I have pasted the codes of .ovpn file above.

Comment: I think we are talking past each other.  Your ovpn files need to either imbed the contents of the appropriate files or you need directives  cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/client.crt (enter)   key/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/client.key (enter)   and you may need to change the ca line to have the full path as well.

Comment: Whenever i append these two 
(
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/client.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/client.key
)  lines, i get following error.

sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn 
Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: client.ovpn
Use --help for more information.

Comment: Are you running openvpn as root?

Comment: yes, [root@centos7 username ] #

Comment: Try temporarily disabling selinux and see if that helps.

Comment: yes i did that already. I think i am missing some .key file or some .cert certificate , since error also shows No certification verification done. I am stuck.

Comment: Dear all,
Problem is solved now. After changing ovpn file (which organization provided), now vpn successful. Thanks all for suggestions and efforts.